# Position and total momentum of center of mass of a bosonic string

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory

Polyakov action of a bosonic string propagating in Minkowskian spacetime is:

$$S[\gamma, X] = \frac{T}{2}\int \mathrm{d}^{2}\sigma{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\gamma^{ab}\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial _{a}X^{\mu}(\sigma)\partial_{b}X^{\nu}(\sigma)\tag{1}$$

Once a conformal gauge is chosen to be $\gamma_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma, \tau) = \lambda(\sigma, \tau)\eta_{\alpha\beta}$, equations of motion for the action in $(1)$ are:

$$\biggr(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\sigma^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\tau^2}\biggr)X^{\mu}(\sigma, \tau) = 0\space\space\equiv\space\space \square X^{\mu}(\sigma, \tau) = 0\tag{2}$$

D'Alembert solution of which can be written as

$$X^{\mu}(\sigma, \tau) = \frac{1}{2}\biggr[X^{\mu}_{L}(\sigma+\tau) + X^{\mu}_{R}(\sigma-\tau)\biggr]\tag{3}$$

Where $L/R$ denote the left/right-moving sectors of the bosonic string. For Dirichlet boundary condition, the sectors satisfy

$$\dot{X}^{\mu}_{L}(\tau) = \dot{X}^{\mu}_{L}(\pi+\tau), \space\space \dot{X}^{\mu}_{R}(-\tau) = \dot{X}^{\mu}_{R}(\pi-\tau)\tag{4}$$

Under a change of variables, $\sigma^{\pm} = \sigma\pm\tau$, the sectors admit a representation in terms of complex Fourier series:

$$\begin{align}\partial_{\sigma^{+}}X^{\mu}_{L}(\sigma^{+}) = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\sum^{\infty}_{n = -\infty}\alpha^{\mu}_{n}e^{-in\sigma^{+}}\space\space \alpha^{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0}\partial_{\sigma^{+}}X^{\mu}_{L}(\sigma^{+})e^{in\sigma^{+}}d\sigma^{+}\\ \partial_{\sigma^{-}}X^{\mu}_{R}(\sigma^{-}) = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\sum^{\infty}_{n = -\infty}\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{n}e^{-in\sigma^{-}}\space\space\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0}\partial_{\sigma^{-}}X^{\mu}_{R}(\sigma^{-})e^{in\sigma^{-}}d\sigma^{-}\end{align}\tag{6}$$

Integrating $(6)$ leads us to

$$\begin{align}X^{\mu}_{L}(\sigma^{+}) = c^{\mu}_{L}+\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\alpha^{\mu}_{0}\sigma^{+} + i\biggr(\sum_{n\neq 0}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\frac{\alpha^{\mu}_{n}}{n}e^{-in\sigma^{+}}\biggr)\\ X^{\mu}_{R}(\sigma^{-}) = c^{\mu}_{R}+\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{0}\sigma^{-} + i\biggr(\sum_{n\neq 0}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\frac{\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{n}}{n}e^{-in\sigma^{-}}\biggr)\end{align}\tag{7}$$

Where the zero-modes are

$$\alpha^{\mu}_{0} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0}\partial_{\sigma^{+}}X^{\mu}_{L}(\sigma^{+})d\sigma^{+}\space\space \tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{0} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0}\partial_{\sigma^{-}}X^{\mu}_{R}(\sigma^{-})d\sigma^{-}\tag{8}$$

Furthermore, from Dirichlet condition $\alpha^{\mu}_{n} = -\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{n}$, and $X^{\mu}(0, \tau)  = X^{\mu}(\pi, \tau) = x^{\mu}$

$$X^{\mu}(\sigma, \tau)\biggr|_{\sigma = 0, \tau = 0} =  \biggr[\frac{1}{2}(c^{\mu}_{L}+c^{\mu}_{R}) + \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\alpha^{\mu}_{0}\tau + \sum_{n\neq 0}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\frac{\alpha^{\mu}_{n}}{n}e^{-in\sigma}\sin(n\tau)\biggr]\biggr|_{\sigma = 0, \tau = 0}\tag{9}$$

From which we conclude that $x^{\mu} = \frac{1}{2}(c^{\mu}_{L}+c^{\mu}_{R})$. Therefore, the mode expansion of an open string under Dirichlet condition is

$$X^{\mu}(\sigma, \tau) =  x^{\mu} + \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\alpha^{\mu}_{0}\tau + \sum_{n\neq 0}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}\frac{\alpha^{\mu}_{n}}{n}e^{-in\sigma}\sin(n\tau)\tag{9}$$

However, in the general mode expansion, why do we define $\alpha^{\mu}_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{'}}{2}}p^{\mu}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the question is - what's your definition of $p^\mu$ that this is difficult to show? To me it's just the total momentum, i.e. something like $p^\mu \sim \int \partial_\tau X^\mu(\sigma,\tau)\mathrm{d}\sigma$ which yields $\alpha_0^\mu\sim p^\mu$ rather immediately.